# How does EVSE gets the SoC of a vehicle in Level 1 and Level 2 chargers, Type2 Gun(IEC62196-2)?

Tags: power-electronics, bms, electric-vehicle

Type2 gun does not allow full-fledged communication between the EV and EVSE, Electric vehicle can only tell the EVSE what state it is in through the control pilot. is it possible for EVSE to share SoC over Type2 gun?

[image: Control Pilot states]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to communicate SOC over a J1772 connection, nor have I seen a level 1 or 2 EVSE that can display the vehicle SOC. What many EVSEs do is display an estimated **change** in SOC. When the EVSE is programmed with the vehicle model or characteristics giving the approximate total watt-hours of the battery, the EVSE can convert Wh delivered to SOC change.

Comment: I still wonder How it is done in the level3 chargers, I guess SoC has to be calculated through the battery voltage, and for this charger is required to have the Voltage vs Soc curve for all different vehicles in the market